# I wanted to adjust the rear derailleur and loosened the cable to begin. The twister shifter was working before loosening, now it isn't

Tags: shimano, gears, grip-shifter

The rear gears (6) were not adjusted properly and the biggest cog was allowing the chain to jump off next to the wheel. I know now I should have just adjusted the L-screw. But didn't realize that at the time, so went on the Internet to look.

I wanted to adjust the rear gears, so checked a forum. I was asked to loosen the cable with the chain on the smallest cog and adjust the up and down for the chain and cogs. All good. Then retighten the cable. After that I couldn't get the twister shift to move at all!

So, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Is the cable loose now? Does the shifter not move at all? Usually you’d loosen the cable clamp screw, then put the shifter and derailleur to the smallest cog. Screw the barrel adjuster almost all the way in. Then pull the cable with pliers and tighten the clamping screw.

Comment: It is very hard to guess anything from your words, only your disappointment. Do you have a photo of the current situation? What happens when you try to pull the derailleur by hand, instead of the cable?

Comment: Oh, and make sure the cable housing is properly seated everywhere and there are no kinks. Also make sure the cable is properly seated in the shifter (there should be a hole somewhere where you could put in a new cable).

Answer (score 5):

This is only a suspicion, but: something I've seen before, when re-cabling such shifters, is that the cyclindrical end stop on the cable isn't seated properly in the correct position, and jams the rotation.  It's possible to push on the cable and push the end stop out of its seat, then pull without pulling it back into place.  This is particularly true if the cable gets twisted, and the bend that naturally forms inside the shifter over time will point the wrong way.

You might get away with loosening it again, jiggling and pulling, perhaps jiggling the shifter as well.  On the other hand you may need to open the covers on the shifter (usually not  hard) and nudge the end stop into place.

Comment: I've had this exact problem.